Constructing a homeomorphism from a CW-complex to the polyhedron of a simplicial complex
I am working on Problem 5-18(b) from John Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds, referenced in this question, and I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out if I am on the right track with my approach.
I think the basic idea here is that, once you've constructed (via the inductive hypothesis) a homeomorphism of $X_{n-1}$ onto its image – which consists of the subcomplex of $K$ consisting in simplices of $K$ whose vertices are $e^k$ for some $k \in \{0,...,n-1\}$ , you construct a homeomorphism $f$ from the closed $n$-cell $\bar{e}$ – which is a closed $n$-cell because $X$ is assumed to be a regular CW-complex. We can start on the boundary, mapping the boundary $\partial e$ to the relevant subcomplex homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ constructed by induction. Then, we choose a point $v_e$ in the interior $e$ and send it to the point $w$ corresponding to the vertex $\{e\}$ of the abstract simplicial complex $\mathcal{K}$ for which $K$ is an isomorphic euclidean complex. Now, for every simplex $\sigma$ inside the image $f(\partial e)$, $w$ forms a simplex $w \star \sigma$ (a cone on $\sigma$). So if $L$ is the subcomplex of $K$ corresponding to $\partial e$ we can form the cone on $L$, $w \star L$, whose polyhedron (I think!) I was able to show in problem 5-17 is homeomorphic to the cone on $|L|$, which is homeomorphic to the cone on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, which is $\overline{\mathbb{B}^n}$. Thus we can form a homeomorphism $\phi: |w \star L| \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{B}^n}$ in which $|L|$ maps to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and thus we can view $|L|$ as the boundary of $|w \star L|$ and we have showed that $|w \star L|$ is in fact a closed $n$-cell. (This is the main aspect of my approach where I feel sketchy.) Thus we have our original homeomorphism $f: \partial e \rightarrow |L|$ which therefore extends (via problem 5-1 from Lee) to a homeomorphism $F: \bar{e} \rightarrow |w \star L|$. Defining our map similarly for all $n$-cells of $X$, we obtain a map on $X_n$ which restricts by induction to a homeomorphism on $X_{n-1}$ and restricts to a homeomorphism on every closed $n$-cell.
Is this essentially the right approach to constructing a homeomorphism on the $n$-skeleton $X_n$? Thanks very much in advance!
